# urllib downloads 0B on one mirror and not another, how do I debug this?

Tags: python, urllib

- I'm using urllib to read from a url. 0B is read, even though the length is 853324.
- When I use the same code on another mirror, it works.
- When I try to download the files in my browser, they both work.

How do I go about debugging this so that I can use python to get the file from both places?

(These servers are made available to the public, I'm not scraping without permission. I can ask the server owner for help, but I'd like to do due diligence first and make sure I'm not missing something)

```
>>> import urllib.request
>>> url = "https://hpfx.collab.science.gc.ca/20220710/WXO-DD/model_gem_global/15km/grib2/lat_lon/12/015/CMC_glb_TCDC_SFC_0_latlon.15x.15_2022071012_P015.grib2"
>>> req = urllib.request.Request(url, method='HEAD', headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
>>> file_response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
>>> file_response.getcode()
200
>>> file_response.read()
b'' <<< EMPTY RESPONSE
>>> for i in file_response.headers.walk():
...     print(i)
... 
Date: Mon, 11 Jul 2022 09:00:19 GMT
Server: Apache
Last-Modified: Sun, 10 Jul 2022 15:47:53 GMT
ETag: "d054c-5e3755bb7bc40"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 853324
Connection: close
```

If i do the same thing with the same file on a different mirror server, It works

```
>>> url = "http://dd.weather.gc.ca/model_gem_global/15km/grib2/lat_lon/12/015/CMC_glb_TCDC_SFC_0_latlon.15x.15_2022071012_P015.grib2"
>>> req = urllib.request.Request(url, method='HEAD', headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
>>> file_response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
>>> file_response.read()
b'GRIB\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\..........' <<< WORKING HEX DUMP
>>> file_response.getcode()
200
>>> for i in file_response.headers.walk():
...     print(i)
... 
Date: Mon, 11 Jul 2022 08:56:15 GMT
Server: Apache
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=63072000; preload
Last-Modified: Sun, 10 Jul 2022 15:47:53 GMT
ETag: "d054c-5e3755bb7bc40"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 853324
X-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge
Connection: close
```

Both servers respond with 200
No exceptions are thrown.

Comment: method='HEAD'? Did you mean method='GET'?

Comment: I don't know the difference? is 'GET' better?

Comment: @user37216 From where did you get the idea that you should use `HEAD` in this context? Did you think to research it in context with all the other possible [HTTP request methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods)?

Comment: @esqew I just went back and looked at github blame. My colleague used it originally and I copied their method. 'HEAD' is everywhere in our codebase. I asked my collegue and he says "it's always worked like this for years". And now I'm amazed it has!

Comment: I'm new to python, I have other specialities in the company (electronics) and they asked me to do this work because python coding is needed more.

Answer (score 1):

You're using method='HEAD', which only requests the headers. An empty response body (as in your first example) is exactly what is supposed to happen. I'm not sure if what the second server is doing is allowed by the relevant RFCs.

If you want response bodies, use method='GET'.